# How were the shogi matches sourced?

Tags: march-comes-in-like-a-lion

"March comes in like a Lion" shows numerous shogi matches between master-level players. I am wondering whether the matches shown in the series are representative for master-level play or whether it's just background material made up by the screenwriters. From what I read about shogi, it sounds like a serious art in Japan, so I was wondering whether the producers put in the effort to e.g. engage some expert players as consultants or reproduce excerpts of actual historic matches.

Comment: Wikipedia can be a good start.

Comment: I did check the German and English wikipedia articles on the series, as well as on shogi, but I didn't see anything mentioned in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean by _actual high-level historic games_? If you are asking shogi is what people play in reality, then yes. According to [日本将棋連盟](https://www.shogi.or.jp/history/story/), the oldest shogi pieces date to AD 1058.

Comment: I've rewritten my question to clarify what I'm curious about

Comment: ' From what I read about shogi, it sounds like a serious art in Japan' - Ah so this is opposed to like chess in the US where we don't necessarily expect they'll be realistic setups and stuff? (My question was going to be 'what about chess in movies/series?', and then I think the answer is the quote at the beginning of this comment.)

Comment: When watching the series, I was wondering whether my impression was accurate that a lot of effort had been put in sourcing the game arrangements given that specific shogi situations were such a central theme. I mean this as opposed to how e.g. "hacking" is depicted in a ridiculously inaccurate manner when used as a plot device or sciency explanations are often total nonsense in movies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand the question as *Are arrangements of shogi pieces in the games drawn in the manga modelled on or reproducing game records of actual games between real professional(-level) players?*.

First, the manga has [a professional player](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%88%E5%B4%8E%E5%AD%A6) as an advisor (He writes columns in interchapter pages). So the arrangements are definitely not random.

According to [a blog post](https://sangencyaya.hatenadiary.com/entry/20100413/1271107642), some arrangements are actually based on real records, though not exactly reproducing them in most cases. So finally, the answer to your question is yes, at least partially.